# how to insert jcombobox value in Mysql database

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jcombobox

how to insert jcombobox value in Mysql database?? code work properly if not use jcombobox??

```
try {
        connect obj = new connect();

        obj.st = obj.con.createStatement();
        boolean a = obj.st.execute("insert into std  values('"+jTextField1.getText()+"', '"+jTextField2.getText()+"','"+jTextField3.getText()+"','"+jTextField4.getText()+"','"+(String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()+"')");
     if(a==false){
             System.out.println("Enter successfully");
         }
         else{
             System.out.println("Enter ");
     }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(studentsetp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to post your db table structure.it will be helpful. it seems to be you are inserting some mis-matched data or less column and too many data you are passing into the insert query

Answer (score 2):

Just try with  `(String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();`,you have to cast to String.

This is your code.

```
obj.st.execute("insert into std  values('"+jTextField1.getText()+"', '"+jTextField2.getText()+"','"+jTextField3.getText()+"','"+jTextField4.getText()+"',"+(String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()+"')");
```

Comment: these expectations occur??
Jun 06, 2014 10:19:27 AM college.managment.system.studentsetp jButton3ActionPerformed
SEVERE: null

Comment: i dont understand,what you are telling?